# как изменить страницу "Веб-страница недоступна"

Tags: android, webview

Хочу изменить страницу "Веб-страница недоступна". Что бы при отсутствии соединения открывался мой html файл (noconnect.htm). Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7522946):

```
WebView mWebView;

...

mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myerrorpage.html");

    }
});
```

В `loadUrl(...)` передается путь к странице, которую Вы хотите отобразить.

Comment: хочется отметить, что `onReceivedError` ведет себя очень странно и на 60% стандартный экран все равно показывается на долю секунды.